# How to generate list of string with Random Characters using python3

Tags: python-3.x

I tried with the below code but it seems not to give the intended output.

```
ran = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase+string.digits) for x in range(10))
```

So the above code gives '6U1S75' but I want output like

['6U1S75', '4Z4UKK', '9111K4',....]

Please help.

Comment: I edited the code bit because i missed ")". Now it is running but not with the intended outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this.

```
list_size = 10
word_size = 4

ran = []

for i in range(list_size):
    rans = ''

    for j in range(word_size):
        rans += random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits)

    ran.append(rans)
```

Though the above solution is clearer and should be preferred, if you absolutely want to do this with list comprehension...

```
list_size = 10
word_size = 4

ran = [
    ''.join([
        random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) 
        for j in range(word_size)
    ]) 
    for i in range(list_size)
]
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I did it in a single line with same trick ```ran = [''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase+string.digits)for _ in range(4)) for _ in range(10)]```

Comment: You can use `random.choices` with `k` value of `word_size` instead of `choice` in a comprehension btw.

Answer (score 2):

I thought this is elegant :

```py
from string import digits, ascii_letters
from random import choices


def rand_list_of_strings(list_size, word_size, pool=ascii_letters + digits):
    return ["".join(choices(pool, k=word_size)) for _ in range(list_size)]
```

I used `ascii_letters` instead of `ascii_uppercase` to have both upper and lower case values, you can edit it to your suiting.

Example use of the above function :

```py
>>> rand_list_of_strings(4, 5)
['wBSbH', 'rJoH8', '9Gx4q', '8Epus']
>>> rand_list_of_strings(4, 10) 
['UWyRglswlN', 'w0Yr7xlU5L', 'p0e6rghGMS', 'Z8zX2Vqyve']
>>>
```

The first argument is the list size, and the second argument is how large each consequent string should be, and the function invocation returns a `list` instance. Do not that this should **not** be used for cryptographic purposes.